# How to change title of BlackBerry BrowserField when a certain link is clicked

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I've been trying to find a way to add a listener to the BlackBerry BrowserField for when the user clicks a link and the URL changes.  I have tried adding a BrowserFieldListener below, but I keep getting a warning message declaring that Document cannot be resolved as a type.  Any suggestions on capturing when a user clicks a link and it takes them to a certain URL?

```
BrowserFieldListener listener = new BrowserFieldListener(){
public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception
    {

          browswerField.setTitle("Example");        
    }

};
browserField.addListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing the declaration of Document somewhere?

I do something similar using the BrowserField to pars HTML, see my [blog posting here](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2011/08/parsing-html-on-blackberry.html).

Comment: For people wanting the import quickly: import org.w3c.dom.Document; (taken from Richards blog)